# Compute the Integral $\int_0^1 1 - F_f(x) dx$ where $F_f(x) = \mu(f^{-1}(-\infty, x])$ and $f(x) = x^2$

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

I need to compute the following integral $\int_0^1 1 - F_f(x) dx$  where   $F_f(x) = \mu(f^{-1}(-\infty, x])$ and $f(x) = x^2$ and $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure.

If I am correct $F_f(x) = \mu(f^{-1}(-\infty, x]) = \mu([0,1]) = 1 $ because we are integrating from $0$ to $1$ or is it $\mu([-1,1]) = 2$ since for all $x \in [-1,1]$ we have $x^2 \in [0,1]$.

So I either have $\int_0^1 1 - 1 dx = 0$ or $\int_0^1 1 - 2dx = -1$

This doesn't seem right but I am not sure why.

Comment: Your $F_f(x)$ should depend on $x$...

Comment: @ZacharySelk so something more like $F_f(x) = \mu(f^{-1}(-\infty, x]) = \mu(0 , x]) = x$

Comment: $f^{-1}(-\infty, x] \neq [0,x]$

Comment: @ZacharySelk $f^{-1} (-\infty , x] = [-x ,x] $ ? Im not sure why this is confusing me. So  I would have $\int_0^1 1-2xdx = 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $f^{-1}(-\infty, x]=[-\sqrt x, \sqrt x]$ if $x\ge 0$ so:

$F_f(x)=\mu ([-\sqrt x, \sqrt x])=2\sqrt x$ for $x \ge 0$

So then you have:

$$\int_0^1 1-2\sqrt x ~ dx$$

Which should be doable.

Comment: thank you! I came across cdf functions and was trying to understand them better.